# How to migrate custom TokenFilter from Lucene.Net 3.0.3 to 4.8

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I have the following custom TokenFilter that works on Lucene.Net 3.0.3 and I need to migrate it to Lucene.Net 4.8:

```
public sealed class AccentFoldingFilter : TokenFilter
{
    private ITermAttribute termAttribute;

    public AccentFoldingFilter(TokenStream input) : base(input)
    {
        termAttribute = this.input.GetAttribute<ITermAttribute>();
    }

    public override bool IncrementToken()
    {
        if (this.input.IncrementToken())
        {
            termAttribute.SetTermBuffer(termAttribute.Term.RemoveDiacritics());
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

`ITermAttribute` no longer exists, I guess I need to use `ICharTermAttribute` but I don't know how to do it.

How to do the same in 4.8?

For reference this is the `RemoveDiacritics` extension method:

```
public static string RemoveDiacritics(this string text)
{
    var normalizedString = text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var c in normalizedString)
    {
        var unicodeCategory = CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c);
        if (unicodeCategory != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(c);
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Although you could use the answer below, do note that Lucene.NET 4.8.0 includes a [ICUNormalizer2Filter](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/4.8.0-beta00014/api/icu/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Icu.ICUNormalizer2Filter.html), an [ICUNormalizer2CharFilter](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/4.8.0-beta00014/api/icu/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Icu.ICUNormalizer2CharFilter.html), and an [ICUFoldingFilter](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/4.8.0-beta00014/api/icu/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Icu.ICUFoldingFilter.html) in the box. However, you may still be inclined to use your existing solution rather than drag in a 20MB+ dependency (ICU4N).

To translate you will need to add the `ICharTermAttribute` to your filter directly (not on the `TokenStream`). The attribute will be pulled out of the shared context of the token stream by calling `GetAttribute<ICharTermAttribute>()`.

```
public sealed class AccentFoldingFilter : TokenFilter
{
    private ICharTermAttribute termAttribute;

    public AccentFoldingFilter(TokenStream input) : base(input)
    {
        termAttribute = this.GetAttribute<ICharTermAttribute>();
    }

    public override bool IncrementToken()
    {
        if (this.m_input.IncrementToken())
        {
            string buffer = termAttribute.ToString().RemoveDiacritics();
            termAttribute.SetEmpty().Append(buffer);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also, the `RemoveDiacritics` method implementation doesn't account for surrogate pairs, which could lead to hard to diagnose bugs down the road.

```
public static string RemoveDiacritics(this string text)
{
    var normalizedString = text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    int inputLength = normalizedString.Length;
    char[] buffer = new char[inputLength];

    // TODO: If the strings are short (less than 256 chars),
    // consider using this (must be unsafe context)

    // char* buffer = stackalloc char[inputLength];

    int bufferLength = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < inputLength;)
    {
        // Handle surrogate pairs
        int charCount = char.IsHighSurrogate(normalizedString, i)
            && i < inputLength - 1
            && char.IsLowSurrogate(normalizedString, i + 1) ? 2 : 1;

        var unicodeCategory = CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(normalizedString, i);
        if (unicodeCategory != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
        {
            buffer[bufferLength++] = normalizedString[i]; // high surrogate / BMP char
            if (charCount == 2)
            {
                buffer[bufferLength++] = normalizedString[i + 1]; // low surrogate
            }
        }
        i += charCount;
    }

    return new string(buffer, 0, bufferLength).Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
}
```